# Ugraded php 5.3 to latest 5.6 now php -v returns nothing

Tags: php

I just upgraded PHP from version 5.3 to the latest 5.6.27 on a centOS 5.6 VPS. Before upgrading php -v returned the version number. Now it returns nothing. php -n -v returns the version number. I understand from searching this means there is an error in the php.ini file.

I have scanned php.ini and have no idea what could be creating the problem or what I should be looking for. Can anyone make suggestions what to look for?

Many Thanks!

Comment: I think `php -i` will parse your .ini and show errors

Comment: It's kinda interesting that the https://secure.php.net/releases/ -page have no mention of a 5.6.27 version... the last version of 5.6 is 26. And, why haven't you upgraded to 7 yet?

Comment: `php -i` doens't return anything. :(
I also thought 5.6.26 was the latest but this is what `php -n -v` returns
`[alpha@ ~]$ php -n -v
PHP 5.6.27 (cli) (built: Oct 14 2016 14:15:48)
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies`
Could this be the issue?
I would love to update to PHP 7 but this system is old and it scares me how many errors/warning would result. The whole system needs to be rewritten.